# Difference between Jetpack Compose ModalDrawer and Scaffold Drawer?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

What exactly is the difference between a `ModalDrawer()` and `Scaffold(DrawerContent)`?  I seem to recall reading somewhere that the `ModalDrawer()` incorporates the navigation component.  I also think I read that you can't use a `ModalDrawer` with `Scaffold`, or that they don't work well together.

When do you want to use one over the other?